# NodeJS + Sequelize extremely slow on Mac M1 Silicon

Tags: node.js, performance, sequelize.js, apple-m1, arm64

Since I use my MacBook Pro with the Apple M1 processor my express.js backend is extremely slow with Sequelize ORM.

Some Facts:

- Executing a simple findOne takes up to 20 seconds on M1 processor. If I execute the SQL directly with DataGrip it takes about 50 ms
- the same backend runs super fast on Intel machines with less hardware specs
- if I execute a function without Sequelize it is also good performance on M1

Any ideas? I was searching for a solution for hours now but I can't find any topics about that problem.

Here my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "apicache": "^1.6.3",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~4.3.4",
    "express": "~4.18.2",
    "fast-folder-size": "^1.7.0",
    "heapdump": "^0.3.15",
    "html-pdf-node": "^1.0.7",
    "http-errors": "~2.0.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "morgan": "~1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.16",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.6",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.30.0",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It was **Sophos Home** - after uninstallation everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem 2 months ago, I tried thousands of solutions, but none of them helped me. After a week I completely removed Node from the system and installed it from scratch and my problem is solved!

I think you should do same! Just remember to install version 16

Apparently, version 18 has many problems that still have problems with more modern systems and architectures.

But if you find a more accurate and better solution, thank you for sharing it with me

Comment: Thanks for your Idea! I already reinstalled node.js more than once. I also removed the cache of npm and removed the node_modules. But nothing helps.

Comment: you're welcome. I'm sorry that this solution didn't work on your system. Really, I never understood why this problem occurs and why there is no solution for it.